# Moving or copying images from a flat directory to subdirectories

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, file-system

I have a huge *Google Photos* directory that is difficult to navigate - there are just too many files so I thougt I need to sort them somehow. I decided to make it simple and group them by date-taken. As I always wanted to learn python I thought I'll give it a try so this is my first take on it.

There is no rocket-science here (yet). It looks for files in the `pictures_path`, groups them by their modified date, enumerates this iterator, creates directories and moves or copies files according to the `whatif` option. This is measured by the `perf_counter()`.

I'd be great if you could take a look at it and tell me whether I did something terribly wrong as a beginner before I let it work with my actual collection.

```
import os
import time
import itertools
import shutil
from pprint import pprint

def format_filemtime(path):
    filemtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime(filemtime))

def group_pictures(whatif=False):
    pictures_path = "C:\\temp\\picturepy\\pictures\\"
    galleries_path = "C:\\temp\\picturepy\\galleries\\"

    start = time.perf_counter()

    picture_names = os.listdir(pictures_path)

    print(f"picture count: {len(picture_names)}")

    pictures_by_mtime = itertools.groupby(picture_names, lambda name: format_filemtime(os.path.join(pictures_path,name)))

    for (dir, picture_names) in pictures_by_mtime:
        path_dir = os.path.join(galleries_path, dir)
        if not os.path.exists(path_dir):
            os.makedirs(path_dir)
            print(f"'{dir}' created.")
        else:
            print(f"'{dir}' already exists.")

        do = shutil.copyfile if whatif else shutil.move
        verb = "copied" if whatif else "moved"

        for file in picture_names:
            do(
                src=os.path.join(pictures_path, file), 
                dst=os.path.join(path_dir, file))                
            print(f"\t'{file}' {verb}.")

    end = time.perf_counter()
    elapsed = round(end - start,2)
    print(f"elapsed: {elapsed} sec")

# --- --- ---

def main():
    group_pictures(whatif=True)
    #group_pictures()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tested it with `VSCode` and it's doing its job pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty decent for a first Python program, so good job on that.

I only have a few small nitpicks

- Some [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations, but nothing major

  1. There should be a `<space>` after the `,`
  2. Line too long (max 79)
- Consider making the directory paths global constants

  [PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)

  ```
  PICTURES_PATH = "C:\\temp\\picturepy\\pictures\\"
  GALLERIES_PATH = "C:\\temp\\picturepy\\galleries\\"
  ```
- I think `whatif` could have a better name

  What if what? It's not really clear what this variable is supposed to do

  Maybe rename it to `keep_original`, because the copy will leave the original intact
- Possible to do the `if else` in one line with unpacking

  > ```
  > do = shutil.copyfile if whatif else shutil.move
  > verb = "copied" if whatif else "moved"
  > ```

  Would become

  ```
  do, verb = (shutil.copyfile, "copied") if keep_original else (shutil.move, "moved")
  ```

Comment: Cool! I can explain the weird `whatif` - my first try was with powershell (but I gave up) and its commandlets use this kind of switch so I followed this bad example but you're right about everything and also `keep_original` is much better :)